# many to many relationships for movie application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many

I am creating an application in which the user can create postings of movies as well as favorite the movie posts of other users. I am confused as to how the many-to-many relationships should be set up in the rails backend.

The user has many movies and can also have many favorites(which are the movie postings but they are just clicking a button to add them to their favorites section) and many user are able to favorite the same movie.

The way I have the relationships and models set up right now.....

```
class CreateFavorites < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
   def change
    create_table :favorites do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :movie_id
     end
   end
end

 class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
 end

  class Movie < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :user
      has_many :comments
      belongs_to :favorite
  end

 class CreateMovies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
       create_table :movies do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.string :genre
       t.string :rating
       t.string :image
       t.string :watch_link
       t.integer :user_id
     end
   end
end

 class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_secure_password
    has_many :movies
    has_many :comments
    has_many :favorites
  end

  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
     def change
       create_table :users do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.string :email
       t.string :username
       t.string :password_digest
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hannah, have you tried my answer?

Comment: I just saw the answer, I'm going to start working on it now and I will let you know how it goes , thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can create favorites association between the `User` and `Movie` models using `has_many :through`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :movies
  has_many :favorite_movies, class_name: 'Favorite', foreign_key: 'user_id'
  has_many :favorites, through: :favorite_movies, source: :movie
end

class Movie < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

It has to work that way.

Now you can get user's favorites like this: `User.first.favorites`